# Problema 2 dominios Apache

Tags: linux, apache, web, servidor

Estoy tratando de configurar 2 dominios en un 1 servidor: 
_Debian Linux 
_Apache2

Cree el siguiente archivo: pclinx.conf , luego habilite con a2ensite , para que quede habilitado y después reinicie el apache2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.pclinx.com.br
ServerAlias *.pclinx.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pclinx


<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/pclinx>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

En /var/www/html/pclinx está el archivo index.html .... pero no se pq razón no logro visualizar nada, no se ve el index.html.

En /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1   www.pclinx.com.br

Página Web: www.pclinx.com.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando hagas el get del sitio web, por ejemplo:

```
curl http://www.pclinx.com.br/index.html
```

ve y revisa el

```
tail /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

que tienes el pedido. **DEBE** estar alli, si no hay una linea con tu pedido, es que no llegas al server web.

Si no es una pedido con código 200 (OK) entonces también tendrás el error registrado en

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

y ahí tendrás una explicación.

Yo me inclinaría a un problema de permisos o que el apache no está sirviendo la página correcta.